# Adding a span tag between the text of anchor tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would you add a span tag before the text inside a hyperlink?
         Right now, I'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").before('<span class="k-icon k-add"></span>');
</script>
```

I tried the above code but the required span is coming before the anchor tag

```
<span class="k-icon k-add"></span><a href="some page">Add</a>
```

I need the link to look like this when it is parsed:

```
<a href="some page"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok @dystroy, i give up, you win the edit battle ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I was just trying to fix the formatting problems...

Comment: @dystroy Me too, was just joking of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add some content at the start of your element :

```
$("a").prepend('<span class="k-icon k-add"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add icons not with js but with pseudo elements in css

It will be something like this:

```
a.k-icon.k-add:before {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    content: '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frsxy8vb/